# Spring Security AuthenticationProvider - extends Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

We have a custom type of User for an application, thus we don't want to use

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String name = authentication.getName();
```

in our

```
public EmployeeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
```

but, because we have different names for incoming POST parameters, for example

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
    String employeeName = authentication.getEmployeeName();
    String employeePassword = authentication.getEmployeePassword();
```

as we are using a custom bean called Employee for the users of the application.

Is it possible to extend Authentication and to replace it in the method authenticate? Shall our EmployeeServiceImplementation implements org.spring.security.core.Authentication as well or should it be implemented in our Employee bean (that would be a bit frustrating) ? I'm a bit confused about how to solve this issue.

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**

According to this great POST [Spring get custom UserDetails in SecurityContextHolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930876/spring-get-custom-userdetails-in-securitycontextholder)
I have now

```
class EmployeeUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
```

and

```
class EmployeeUserDetails extends Employee implements UserDetails, Authentication{
```

Now I have the class

```
class EmployeeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
```

and I want to change the method

```
 org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider#authenticate(Authentication authentication)
```

so I can use `EmployeeUserDetails` instead of `Authentication`?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the method signature, but you can set an EmployeeUserDetails inside the Authentication object returned from the authenticate method.
You can do that using setDetails method of Authentication object