# how to can get paremeters with @PreAuthorize in Spring security

Tags: java, spring, security

I want to get parameter with PreAuthorize annotation in Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("#id != authentication.id")
public boolean remove(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }
```

But I get an error :

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/Spring_sec4] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to evaluate expression '#id != authentication.id'] with root cause
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken' - maybe not public?
```

how to can do it ?

---

I use from this code for get current user in method of controller :

```
UserApp currentUserApp = (UserApp) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

then

```
if ( currentUserApp.getId().equals(id) ) {
    throw new Exception("You can't remove yourself");
}
```

Comment: The `Authorization` doesn't have an `id` property.

Comment: thanks, how I can do it ? do you have idea ?

Comment: Whta is `id` here? And what do you want to check.

Comment: `id` is a field in the user class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Authorization` does not have an `id` property by default.

You need to implement `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` to have an `id` field: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39931142/2039546

You can use it later by typing `authentication.principal.id`.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/remove/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@PreAuthorize("#id != authentication.principal.id")
public boolean remove(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }
```