# I don't know how to extract the id of principal

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I have this code ant I want to extract the UUID of principal and give it as a parameter in the saveProperty function. But I don't know how. Can someone help me?

```
    public String saveProperty(@ModelAttribute("property") Property property, Principal principal) {
        //UUID userUUID= principal.getId();
        propertyService.saveProperty(property, userUUID);
        //propertyService.saveProperty(property, UUID.randomUUID());
        return "redirect:/properties";
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete implementation of `Principal` interface on your project? That interface does not have a field named `id`

Comment: I have a class named CustomUserDetails. `public class CustomUserDetails extends User {

    private final UUID id;

    public CustomUserDetails(UUID id, String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

You would implement the `UserDetailsService` interface and the `UserDetails` interface in another class as in [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39931142/2039546), you can get your model containing id in your controller class like this:

```java
public String saveProperty(@ModelAttribute("property") Property property, 
                           Authentication authentication) {
    CustomUser customUser = (CustomUser)authentication.getPrincipal();
    UUID userUUID = customUser.getId();
    propertyService.saveProperty(property, userUUID);
    return "redirect:/properties";
}
```

**`OR`**

```java
public String saveProperty(@ModelAttribute("property") Property property, 
                           @AuthenticationPrincipal CustomUser customUser) {
    UUID userUUID = customUser.getId();
    propertyService.saveProperty(property, userUUID);
    return "redirect:/properties";
}
```